# How to disable play automatically on animation in Unity3d 4.5.1

Tags: unity, 3d, animation

Where is the option to disable the 'Play Automatically' function for animations in Unity3d 4.5.1. In previous versions, there was a button under the Animation tab to disable the play automatically:
 [image]

But now in Unity3d 4.5.1, there is no 'Play Automatically' checkbox, instead this is here:
[image]

If anyone knows how to disable the play automatically in this version of Unity, I would really appreciate if you could explain how to do it and where to go to do it because I am pretty new to Unity and am not too sure where things are. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With new animation system, animations are handled by `AnimatorController` component.

If your animation start automatically, it means that the clip is the default one (orange color) in the controller graph. To prevent this on Behavior on start you have 2 way:

1. Keep AnimatorController component disabled until you don't need it.
2. Use an empty state with no clip as default (inside the controller): transition to your animation clip must be explicitly activated

Comment: do you happen to know how to disable the animatorcontroller component in a script?

Comment: @TheRadGamerDan: GetComponent<AnimatorController>().enabled = false;

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the title went from Animation to Animator which seems to indicate that you might need to look at a different menu. I found [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animation.html) in the unity manual. Perhaps look for an Animation menu.

Comment: When you're on the animation, in the inspector sidebar it has this which is the 'animator' thing [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/3xr5js)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make an empty transition and set that as the default transition and in JavaScript type this:

```
 var FallerObject : GameObject;

 function OnTriggerEnter (Other : Collider){
   if(Other.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
     FallerObject.animation.Play("TypeAnimationNameHere");
   }
}
```

It will play the animation when you collide with the object that has the tag of: `"Player"` and will play the animation that `FallerObject` has.